# Bash forwarding stdout, stderr and pipe to external program

Tags: bash

I've a Bash command with runs a python script and produce outputs on stdout and stderror.

Normal and error logs are written to separate files with this command:

```
python3 file.py >> normal.log 2>> error.log
```

Additionally, stdout and stderr shall be forwarded to an external program (e.g. logToTelegram.sh):

```
python3 file.py 2>&1 | logToTelegram.sh
```

Is there a way to implement both during one execution, write log files (normal and error) and pipe stdout and stderror together to the program logToTelegram.sh?

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
( python3 file.py 2> >(tee -a error.log) > >(tee -a normal.log) ) | logToTelegram.sh
```

Note that `2> >(tee ...)` has to be placed before `> >(tee ...)` for this to work correctly. For simplicity, both `tee` commands output to stdout, eliminating the need for `2>&1` before piping to `logToTelegram.sh`.

---

Or, to stay closer to the original code and to be more precise:

```
( python3 file.py > >(tee -a normal.log) 2> >(tee -a error.log >&2) ) 2>&1 | logToTelegram.sh
```

Here, the first `tee` outputs to stdout, while the second `tee` outputs to stderr, thus `2>&1` is required to send all output to `logToTelegram.sh`.

Comment: @Freude: please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you.